# A Ramsey-type result for families of subsets

Tags: set-theory, ramsey-theory, infinitary-combinatorics

Let $S$ be a set of cardinality $\aleph_1$. Consider the directed family $\mathcal{C}$ (here *directed* means *directed with respect to the inclusion*) of all countably infinite subsets of $S$. Suppose that

$$\mathcal{C} = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \mathcal{C}_n$$

for some families $\mathcal{C}_n$. Does it follow that for some $n_0$ the family $\mathcal{C}_{n_0}$ contains an uncountable, directed subfamily?

Of course, at least one $\mathcal{C}_n$ is uncountable, so let us take this one. Must it contain an uncountable directed subfamily?

Comment: Do you assume $\sf CH$ or something?

Comment: I don't know...

Comment: I'm assuming your $\infty$ in the union is $\omega$?

Comment: By directed do you mean directed under unions or under intersections? And should the $\mathcal{C}_n$ be disjoint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Letting $S = \omega_1$, one of the $C_n$'s must contain uncountably many ordinals and hence an uncountable linearly ordered subfamily.

Also not every uncountable family contains one. For example, an almost disjoint family.

Comment: Clever. I was wondering where you've been.

Comment: I've been busy typing a paper. It is almost finished. I would like to talk about it sometime in the student seminar if you have a free slot.

Comment: When it rains, it pours. Dor wanted to talk and Yair wanted to give a series of talks. I'll ask on Sunday and give you an answer by Monday, I hope.

Answer (score 1):

Improving on hot-queens result, note that this is true even if S is countably infinite. To show this identify S with rationals and note that some $C_n$ must contain uncountably many reals where we view a real x as the set of rationals less than x.